# matching duplicated and or omitted words in a sentences or paragraph and restyling them in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: jquery, speech

I request for reference if my question has answers else where.

I am creating a reading competition app in JavaScript. I have 2 divs, one for the text to be read and the other to display the styled text once read.

i have created an app which works fine. if i read the text in div1 it outputs correctly in the other div2.

**my challenge is matching duplicated or omited words**

the text to be read.
**hi all, am trying to read this passage. incase i fail help me out**

the result should be such that;
if the word(s)/text/sentence is read correctly, it should be formatted green in color;
if the word(s)/text/sentence is read incorrectly, it should be formatted red in color;
if the word(s)/text/sentence is skipped, it should be formatted blue in color;
if the word(s)/text/sentence is read repeatedly, it should be formatted strike through;
as shown
[image]

my html code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Speech to text Converter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h3 align="center">Speech to text converter JavaScript</h3>
    
    <div id="result2">
        most of the people in kenya are poor according to the latest information on the televisions. according to the news passed yesterday, the president of repuvloc of kenya has promised to tax kenyans. 
    </div>
    <button id="mybtn"><i class="fa fa-microphone btn btn-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    <button id="mybtn2">check</button>

    <div id="result"></div>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jqueryScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my css

```
    body{font-family: Open Sans;}
#result{
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #bbb;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
button{
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 550px;
    left: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#result, #result2{
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #bbb;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

my javascript

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
        
    
        $("#mybtn").on("click",() => {
    
            if('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window) {
    
                var speechRecognizer = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
                speechRecognizer.continuous = true;
                speechRecognizer.interimResults = true;
                speechRecognizer.lang = 'en-US';
                speechRecognizer.start();
    
                var finalTranscripts = $("#result").text() + '\n';
    
                speechRecognizer.onresult = function(event) {
                var interimTranscripts = '';
                for(var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++){
                    var transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript;
    
                    transcript.replace("\n", ". <br>");
    
                    if(event.results[i].isFinal) {
                        finalTranscripts += transcript + ". ";
                    }else{
    
                        interimTranscripts += transcript;
    
                    }
                }
                    $("#result").html(finalTranscripts + '<span style="color: #999">' + interimTranscripts + '</span>');
                };
    
                    speechRecognizer.onerror = function (event) {
                };
    
    
            }else {
                 $("#result").html('Your browser is not supported. Please download Google chrome or Update your Google chrome!!');
            }   
    
        });
    
    
        $("#mybtn2").on("click",()=>{
            var arr = $("#result2").text().split(" ");
            var arr2 = $("#result").text().split(" ");
             var string = " ";
    
            console.log($('#result').html());
    
            arr2.map (function (word, i) {
                if (word == arr[i]){
                    string += "<span style= 'color:green;'>" + word + "</span><span> </span>"; 
                } else{
                    string += "<span style='color:red;'>" + word + "</span><span> </span>"; 
                }
            });
    
            $('#result').html(string);
        });
        

});
```

Comment: You didn't mention the problems you're facing

Comment: One issue that you may be facing, is that you're not outputting the error message:  speechRecognizer.onerror = function(event) {
        console.log('Speech recognition error detected: ' + event.error);
      };

Comment: @james no error in the above code; the problem is stated in the question

Comment: It doesn't look like any of the code you provided is attempting to match the words in the two divs and then styling them accordingly.  Where is that part?

Comment: @james I have edited the question. kindly check it out

Comment: If you use split on the text, you need to make sure the text is formatted so the splits line up with the attempted speech.  This is working (mostly) for me.  The word "kenya" is in lowercase in your text, and the speech API automatically formats it as a title as "Kenya".  https://jsfiddle.net/shavertech/9dze23oy